# Identify this unusually-shaped, orange-colored fruit that grows in pairs?

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

The photos below were taken on the island of [Penghu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penghu) in the [Taiwan straight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_Strait) in October. This was in a public place and the small tree (about 3 meters tall, trunk perhaps 8 to 10 cm diameter) had probably been planted, so we can't presume it to be indigenous.

Each fruit was about 6 or 7 cm long, the skin was bright orange and seemed a bit waxy. The shape was a little bit like a banana-shaped American football in that it was divided into four quadrants. They attach to a stem in pairs and extend horizontally (sideways) rather than hang down.

**Question:** What could this gravity defying fruit-bearing tree be?

The first image is cropped, zoomed and sharpened in order to highlight textures.

[image: fruit seen in Penghu island]

[image: fruit seen in Penghu island]

[image: fruit seen in Penghu island]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The seed pods reminded me of the Apocynaceae, so I searched for "apocynaceae china" and found this University of Hawaii [page](http://www.botany.hawaii.edu/faculty/carr/page23.htm) where it is identified as *Stemmadenia litoralis*.  However, a little more looking it seems *Tabernaemontana litoralis* may be the preferred name.  There is some debate [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Anyone_know_if_this_plant_is_Tabernaemontana_or_Stemmadenia).  This [book](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=A%20revision%20of%20Tabernaemontana%20two:%20the%20new%20world%20species%20and%20Stemmadenia.&author=%22Leeuwenberg,%20A.%20J.%20M.%22&publication_year=1994&isbn=0947643745) may hold the final answer regarding the genus.

Your picture of the fruit is one of the best one I could find on the internet. There is another good one [here](http://www.starrenvironmental.com/images/search/?q=Stemmadenia+litoralis) with other pictures of the plant.

You were also correct that as a planted tree it might not be native.  This plant comes from Central America.

Comment: Wow that was quick, thank you for the thorough answer! I don't think this will become as popular as chili peppers (from the Americas as well I think) but it certainly is interesting to look at.

Comment: Locals call it the "Lanyu Tabernaemontana," (named after Lanyu island to the East) which may be classified as  Tabernaemontana dichotoma (Roxb. ex Wall.), [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tabernaemontana+dichotoma&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEx5q06-vkAhULj54KHbwtBiEQ_AUIESgB&biw=1184&bih=635&dpr=1.62"), or Tabernaemontana subglobosa (Merr.). [Plants of Taiwan](http://tai2.ntu.edu.tw/specimen/specimen.php?taiid=092209) at the National Taiwan University.

Comment: @GenTest thanks for all the additional information! One of the images in your link leads to [toxbaselanka](http://www.toxbaselanka.info/plants.aspx). While I'd never thought to try to taste it, I was surprised to see it on a website of toxic plants!

Comment: @uhoh It's in the same dogbane family Apocynaceae as oleandor. The [Tabernaemontana](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/tabernaemontana) genus contains lots of toxin-producing species, and [dichotoma's](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-TW&u=http://edresource.nmns.edu.tw/ShowObject.aspx%3Fid%3D0b81d9e11d0b81d9e1420b81dc87ce&prev=search) sap may cause redness and swelling if it comes in to contact with the skin. Though it does also contain [medicinal compounds and uses.](https://www.cmtcmp.mohw.gov.tw/PLANT_ENG.ASPX?No=0774).